# Replacing NA instead of "N/A" with str_replace() from forcats does not work

Tags: r, dplyr, forcats

I am using `str_replace()` from `forcats` library for replacing my character `"N/A"`'s in ordinary `NA`'s, so I wrote the next lines:

`str_replace(as.character(iris$Species), "setosa", NA)`

It says that requires a character for the replacement object, this one actually works:

`str_replace(as.character(iris$Species), "setosa", "NNAA")`

Does anybody know if is it possible to replace it with `NA` without subseting `[]`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `NA_character_` since this is of type `character`.

Comment: It atcually works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Or use `na.strings` in `read.table`

Comment: The package naniar does also offer some neat functionality to work with NAs. Just for completeness, probably not worth the dependency if it's only this special case.
naniar::replace_with_na(iris, replace = list(Species = "virginica"))

Comment: You could also use `dpylr`: `na_if(iris$Species, "setosa")`

Comment: FYI, there are at least seven types of `NA`, all different in a sense: `NA` (class `logical`), `NA_integer_`, `NA_real_`, `NA_complex_`, `NA_character_`, `c.POSIXct(NA)` (and technically `c.POSIXlt(NA)`, though it's really just a `list` with other `NA` values in it), and `c.Date(NA)`. Typically any use of `NA` is coerced to the same class as the surrounding values in the vector, but functions that enforce explicit same-class, this is insufficient as `logical` is not the same as `character`.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you don't want to subset doesn't mean you should use str_replace where you could do an exact string comparison:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(iris)
DT[,Species:=ifelse(Species=="setosa", NA_character_, "setosa")]
# or simpler
DT[,Species:=ifelse(Species=="setosa", NA, "setosa")]
# or simpler
DT[Species=="setosa",Species:=NA]
```